# JQuery UI tabs 1.10 equivalent

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there equivalent code for jQuery UI 1.10?

This works fine in previous versions but ajaxOptions are deprecated now.

```
$('#mytabs').tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataFilter: function(result){
            var data = $.parseJSON(result);
            return data.myhtml;
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#TheTab').tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'html';
        ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data) {
            return $(data).find('#MYCONTENT').html();
        };
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function(data) {
            ui.panel.html('<b>Something went wrong with the TABS-documentation ;)</b>');
        });
    }
});
```